# Use FILE_URI from camera plugin in ngSrc

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I use `ionic-native` library to access the camera plugin with the following options:

`let options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: 1,
      sourceType: 1,
      allowEdit: false,
      encodingType: 1,
      mediaType: 0,
      correctOrientation: true,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      cameraDirection: 1
    };`

After taking the picture, I get the `FILE_URI` as `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.testApp/cache/1461661383435.png`
But when I use it in the `ngSrc` property of the `img` tag, It just displays an empty block.
While inspecting with chrome, the request for the image has the status of `(blocked:other)`

Also I don't want to use `DATA_URL`, since it degrades the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was suggested in [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-local-image-showing-in-view-on-device/30647/6).

It is EXPLICITLY needed to allow access to local file resource at Android 4.4+.

Add the following lines to the `config.xml`:

`<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />`

And also set the `Content-Security-Policy` in `index.html` as

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

This doesn't work when using **live reload**.